# Reductive groups over number rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, arithmetic-geometry

Let $F$ be a number field.

If $G$ is a reductive group over $\mathcal{O}_F$ then we can look where $G\otimes \mathbb{C}$ fits in the classification of complex reductive groups and get a "standard model" $G_{\mathrm{st}}$. The algebraic group $G$ will differ from $G_{\mathrm{st}}$ at only finitely many places.

Is it true that if we fix $G\otimes \mathbb{C}$ and fix the places of difference then there is only finitely many reductive groups over $\mathcal{O}_F$ we could have started with?

Comment: Welcome new contributor. You will find the answer to your question, and presumably even more, in  https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.04526

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar You could post that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

See [Javanpeykar and Loughran - Good reduction of algebraic groups and flag varieties](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.04526).